# How to remember last window position in GNOME 3?

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome

Whenever I start a GUI application, the application window starts at the upper left of the screen. This is annoying, because I want them to appear at center. I pull them to the center but after quitting they again starts at their upper left position.

I want the window manager to remember the last position to be remembered. How can I do that? I am using GNOME 3.6.2 on Fedora 18.

Comment: Well, It is up to the program to store and restore the window position. So do you have a specific program that isn't doing so?

Comment: @DanD. I think they are ALL! But I have test with gVim, Emacs, gnome-terminal, gnome sudoku and nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to appear in the center of the screen than install Gnome Tweaks
In Tweaks go to Windows section and turn Center New Windows on.
But after that all opened windows and applications will be centered.